# PHP action not receiving Post variables from Python Script

Tags: php, python, symfony, post

I am using a small python script to post to my web server. Now that it successfully connects I am getting an error returned saying that my values cannot be null. When I use PostMan plugin for chrome I do not get an error and I get a successful return message.

Here is my post function in Python:

```
temperature = {"tempF": 20, "tempC": 70}

def post():
    threading.Timer(1800.0, post).start()
    temperature = read_temp()
    data = temperature
    data['room'] = 'Server Room'
    print(data)

    url = 'http://url.to.server'
    query = data 
    res = requests.post(url, data=query)
    print(res.text)
```

And here is how I pull in the variables with my PHP(symfony) action:

```
public function updateTemperatureAction(Request $request)
{
    $tempF = $request->request->get('tempF');
    $tempC = $request->request->get('tempC');
    $room = $request->request->get('room');

    if(empty($tempF)) throw new \Exception("temperature F is empty");

    if(empty($tempC)) throw new \Exception("temperature C is empty");

    if(empty($room)) throw new \Exception("Room is empty");


    $temperature  = new Temperature();
    $temperature->setTemperatureF($tempF);
    $temperature->setTemperatureC($tempC);
    $temperature->setRoom($room);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($temperature);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response($room);
}
```

Here is my error:

```
                        <h1>Oops! Something went wrong.</h1>
    <p>
        The server returned a "<strong>500 Internal Server Error</strong>" error. Please contact the website administrator to address this issue.
    </p>
    <p>
        <small>
            temperature F is empty
        </small>
    </p>

                                    <div class="row" id="footer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        &copy; Shawmut Printing 2014 <span id="epms_query_time"></span> <span id="data_set_last_updated"></span>
    </div>
</div>
                            </div>
        </div>
                <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                <script src="/js/initialize.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/interface.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurred because I was using HTTP and not HTTPS